# What is the best way for a smooth transition from 'relative' position to 'fixed' even if it is faked (fullscreen like effect)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

despite the fact that it's a simple question, I didn't find any satisfying answer yet.

I have a video element on screen that has position relative. When the user click on that element it should become `position:fixed` and be in full screen mode until the user click on it again.

I have managed to do it but transition are not smooth. Here is what I've got so far: [codepen](https://codepen.io/seb-rom-o/pen/ExoQBxB)

Naturally the item should fit into the viewport size when fullscreen.

I have checked these 3 SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304645/css-relative-to-fixed-position-css-transition),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376153/smooth-transition-from-position-relative-to-fixed),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897630/how-to-make-the-transition-from-relative-position-to-fixed-position-smooth)) but none did answer my question

My original project is using React, so I'll be glad if this can be achieved only with CSS although I am open to any javascript answers.

Comment: I think the thing to do is: 1) duplicate the image; 2) add a transition on the second image, in order to scale up as much as possible and also let the opacity decrease for a smoother effect; 3) delete the second image and set `position: fixed` on the first one. In this way it will look like the image transitioned from position relative to fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
    #page {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56%; /* 16/9 ratio */
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation-name: Animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
}
```

Here you can use this and setup according to you

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for the moment...could you provide a working example please :)

Comment: what error are you getting? Because i Just run this code on your given CodePen Link

Comment: The error is that it suddently goes to the middle of the screen, then scale up until it is very bigger than the view port. I would like it to go smoothly from it's relative position to match the size of the viewport. I tried it on firefox and chrome, it's the same issue

Answer (score 0):

check this out!

```js
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", () => document.querySelector("img").classList.toggle("fullscreen"));
```

```css
   #page {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56%; /* 16/9 ratio */
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation-name: Animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='page'>
  <div>
    CLICK ON THE IMAGE TO TOGGLE FULL SCREEN. 
  </div>
  <div id='img-container'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/10/1920/1080/?blur=2' />
  </div>
  <div>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi getting the same error than @Rushabh Gandhi answer

Comment: I see! This means there is something else that is not working I will have a look at it and will get back to you bro!